# Which framework to use for a web app needing non-trivial server-side logic?

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I want to write a web app that has some not-so-trivial logic on the backend (and a database).

I'm primarily a Java developer but I am really interested in web and mobile development so this is a fun project for my portfolio and does not need to be scalable.

I have built web apps with C#/ASP.NET/SQLServer as well as Java/SpringFramework/MySQL in the past, but I think

1. both of those are overkill for this app; and
2. I want to diversify my experience so I want to pick a framework I haven't worked with before.

The framework needs to be one that is in good demand at present in the job market in the US. The client-side interface needs to be fluid and responsive.

I have heard of Python/Django, and Ruby/Rails. I wonder if there are others too and *what backend language they would commonly work with*?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of Flask? http://flask.pocoo.org/

How about node.js? https://nodejs.org/en/

For mobile how about React Native? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: Hadn't heard of Flask, will look into it. I'm just reading up on Node.js at the moment. Is React Native the same as ReactJS? Also, can these talk to a database and do some logic using that data before sending the client data to display? Thank you @puffballjack.

Comment: @coffeeeee They're both different. ReactJS is a javascript library for both server-side and developing interfaces for a web app. React Native is a mobile dev framework which is based on React.JS

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, and ReactJS is just the view in MVC. You will want to look at Node.js for handling your database.